# How to call the methods defined in the surfaceview presented in library to our activity?

Tags: android, methods, surfaceview

I am writing a library in which surfaceview is also defined in the library itself. but when i tried to call the methods defined in surfaceview i am getting exception. Please help me with asolution
this is the code for surfaceview

```
public class AndroidGrapics extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    public SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = null;

    public DrawingBoard(Context context) {
            super(context);

            //Retrieve the SurfaceHolder instance associated with this SurfaceView.
            surfaceHolder = getHolder();

            //Specify this class (DrawingBoard) as the class that implements the three callback methods required by SurfaceHolder.Callback.
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    }

    //SurfaceHolder.Callback callback method.
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            //Create and start a drawing thread whose Runnable object is defined by this class (DrawingBoard).
           // new Thread(this).start();
    }
    public Canvas getCanvas()
    {
        return surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    }

    public void render(Canvas canvas,Paint paint) {
        // canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            //Fill the entire canvas' bitmap with 'black'.
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            //Instantiate a Paint object.
            Paint paint1 = paint;
            //Set the paint color to 'white'.
            paint1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            //Draw a white circle at position (100, 100) with a radius of 50.
            canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, paint1);

    }

    //Neither of these two methods are used in this example, however, their definitions are required because SurfaceHolder.Callback was implemented.
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder sh, int f, int w, int h) {}
    @Override 
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder sh) {}
```

}

and this is the activity

```
public class Activity7s extends Activity implements Runnable{
DrawingBoard draw;
Paint paint=new Paint();
Canvas canvas;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    draw= new DrawingBoard(this);
    System.out.println("_______________________________"+draw.surfaceHolder);
    //Set the content view to a new instance of DrawingBoard.

     //canvas = draw.getCanvas();

    System.out.println("--------------------------"+canvas);
    new Thread(this).start();
    setContentView(draw);
}

@Override
 public void run() {
    canvas = null;


        while(true)
     {
       if(!surface.getSurface().isValid())
    {
        continue;
    }

    try {
        canvas = draw.getCanvas();
        System.out.println("-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb-"+draw.getCanvas());
        synchronized (draw.surfaceHolder) {
            draw.render(draw.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(),paint);
        }
    } finally {
        System.out.println("--------------------------"+canvas);
        // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
        // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
        // inconsistent state
        if (canvas != null) {
            draw.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(draw.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas());
        }
    }

   }
```

}

}

and the logcat error is

```
   04-05 17:57:44.480: W/dalvikvm(3817): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
```

04-05 17:57:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(3817): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-153
04-05 17:57:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(3817): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 17:57:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(3817):     at com.example.sexample.AndroidGrapics.render(AndroidGrapics.java:39)
04-05 17:57:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(3817):     at com.example.sexample.Activity7s.run(Activity7s.java:35)
04-05 17:57:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(3817):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Comment: You're throwing an NPE from AndroidGrapics.java line 97.  Can you point out where that is in your code?  Also, it looks like you pasted the same chunk of constructor code in multiple times -- please clean up the code in the question.

Comment: hi fadden, just updated the code. and that NPE is coming at following line                         canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + width - 1, y + height - 1, paint);

Comment: Sounds like a null `Canvas`.  Are you waiting for the `Surface` to become ready (`surfaceCreated()` callback)?

Comment: hi i am not using any callback methods

Comment: The cleanest approach is to wait for the callback to announce that the Surface is ready.  The less-clean way is to check `SurfaceHolder().getSurface()` for non-null, and check `Surface.isValid()`, before attempting to use the Surface.

Comment: Added the callback to the surface but still i am getting null pointer Exceptioon for the canvas object

Comment: Put a log message in the callback.  Make sure you see it happen *before* you try to use the Surface.  The code you added to the question has the callback but the callback isn't doing anything.  For an example, see "Multi-surface test" in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), which doesn't actually do anything until `surfaceChanged()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the solution

I'm just added following lines in the run method.

```
    if(!sHolder.getSurface().isValid())
       {
        continue;
            }
```

now its working fine.

updated the code in the question.